# jQuery only firing last class in multiple-class click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of links like so:

```
<a href="#internalLink1" class="classA">This has Class A</a>
<a href="#internalLink2" class="classB">This has Class B</a>
<a href="#internalLink3" class="classA classB">This has Class A and Class B</a>
```

And here's the corresponding jQuery:

```
$('.classA').click(function(){
// do class A stuff
});

$('.classB').click(function(){
// do class B stuff
});
```

Currently, when I click on the first link with Class A, it does the Class A stuff like it's supposed to. Similarly, when I click on the second link with Class B, it does the Class B stuff like it's supposed to. No worries there.

My issue is, when I click on the third link with BOTH classes, it only fires the function for whichever class comes last (in this case, class B. If I put class A at the end instead, it performs class A's function). I want it to fire both. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: To those posting fiddles, nearly all of them work, so as many have said, it's most likely not my code, but the way it displays in my file. For a little more clarification, I was teaching myself some jQuery and decided to try making a (very) simple "Choose Your Own Adventure" type game.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bUGyA/

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but no it doesn't.  There's something else going on here, probably a conflict in the two functions that *are* running.

Comment: my guess is you have a logic problem firing both click handlers. log to console within both and you will see they both fire

Comment: Weird, it worked for me, too, but I had to change the console.log to alert or else nothing showed. Must be something else in my file. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Working fine http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/JAZS5/. Is your site live ???

Comment: @user1134644 - did you have the console open? If you're using Chrome hit F12.

Comment: @user1134644 - What version of jQuery are you using? This shouldn't be an issue, however. Your code should work as you desire. Your issue is most-likely in that you are using anchor tags and might be redirected before the second event fires. Although, I doubt the event wouldn't fire in time. Can you post more code?

Comment: It must be firing in whatever order, but it doesn't fire both at once. Are you sure that once the first class get fired, it doesn't go on to the next event after its execution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue here. See the JSBin post here.

http://jsbin.com/IHUkesa/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Well, that does work as written, but that's essentially a third event ("This has class A and B"). I don't want it to say singly "This has class a and class b", I want two separate events, "This has class A" and "This has class B". Thoughts?

Comment: They are two separate events, it only says something different because that's what the link says. Both functions alert the link text. When you click the link with both classes you receive two identical alerts

Comment: TLDR, just change the alerts to say "this is class.."

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.classA').click(function () {
                alert("classA");
            });
            $('.classB').click(function () {
                alert("classB");
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <a href="#internalLink1" class="classA">This has Class A</a>
<a href="#internalLink2" class="classB">This has Class B</a>
<a href="#internalLink3" class="classA classB">This has Class A and Class B</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this different from what the OP posted?

Comment: You need to see the lengthy updates the OP made. Code is much different now.